# Unable to open Eclipse IDE due to missing symlink

Tags: eclipse

I'm not a big fan of Eclipse but sometimes I use it to deploy apps on Google app-engine. So today morning I woke and was all set to deploy my new python app on Google's app engine and that's when noticed the below quoted error.

> An error has occurred. See the log file
>   /home/rupali/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/1336830746877.log.

I tried running a few commands suggested by forums but they returned with an error.

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

> There is only one alternative in link group java:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java Nothing to configure.

Help me please !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I too had the same problem, it seemed like an older version of java was copied into the home directory under .swt. By Creating a symbolic link to /usr/lib/jni/libswt I was able to solve my issue.

Run the beow command in the terminal to fix it.

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or, if `~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/` doesn't exist (using 32-bit) this worked for me:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/
```