# problem in eclipse installation in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, eclipse

Have tried more than dozen times to install Eclipse version available in the Ubuntu Software Center still to no avail. Every time I try to install it shows error i.e. unable to install. Have tried to install it using terminal as well with still the same results. After installation it refuses to run. What to do or any other packages I can use instead of Eclipse. Mainly trying to run java programs through eclipse.
Thanks for the time.
Am using Ubuntu 12.04 on x86-64 bit architecture.

Comment: Please add the error messages to your question as they may help point to the answer.

Comment: could you give some error log? what JVM do you use?

Comment: similar question here http://askubuntu.com/q/138019/71679 maybe it can help

Comment: /home/srijan/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/1340865342535.log. Not even able to locate the log file in the system. Tried installing NetBeans it works fine. Have installed jdk 6 in the system. Any suggestions?

Comment: you will be subject to many bugs with the portable installation

Comment: The only important point to remember is: Stick to the Basics. The bugs do seem to creep up from time to time but little tweaks here and there will get you to the desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow following steps:

1. Install JDK 1.6 by following steps mentioned at http://www.devsniper.com/ubuntu-12-04-install-sun-jdk-6-7/
2. Download an eclipse IDE for 64 bit linux and extract it.

Hope this will help.

Thank you,
Praveen

Comment: Just had to manually install it by directly downloading it from the eclipse website. Anyways the solution u mentioned Praveen is the correct solution. Thanks Praveen.

Comment: @Praveen please never include `hope this helps`, `thanks`, `Praveen`, `good luck`, `well wishes`, `God bless`, `try this`, or any other irrelevant text in your posts.